# Method to check a Object's variables within an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having issues creating the following two methods using an ArrayList object:

1. existTextbook(): checks whether a given textbook is in the catalogue. existTextbook() accepts the title and the author and returns true or false. True if the textbook is in the catalogue,  false otherwise.
2. deleteTexbook():  deletes a textbook from the catalogue. deleteTextbook() accepts a textbook title as  parameter and deletes the textbook if it exists.

Searching the Java API, the closest method I can find for the first method is the contains method but it takes an object as a parameter, not a String object within the Textbook object like the title or author. The same is true for the remove method for the second method taking an object of the ArrayList as a parameter.

Any hints on how to have a method look at each Textbook object String title or author, then return true if a match is found, or to delete the Textbook object containing the Textbook object String title or author?

Here's my code so far:

Textbook Class

```
package Ex1;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Textbook 
{
private String category, title, author;
private int year;
private double price;

public Textbook (String category, String title, String author, int year,
                 double price)
{
    this.category = category;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.year = year;
    this.price = price;
}

public String toString()
{
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    String description;

    description = "Category: " + category + "\n";
    description += "Title: " + title + "\n";
    description += "Author: " + author + "\n";
    description += "Year: " + year + "\n";
    description += "Price: " + fmt.format(price) + "\n" + "\n";

    return description;
}

}
```

Catalogue Class

```
package Ex1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Catalogue 
{
private ArrayList <Textbook> catalogue;

public Catalogue ()
{
    catalogue = new ArrayList<Textbook>();
}

public void addTextbook (Textbook t) 
{
    catalogue.add(t);
}

public boolean existTextbook(String title, String author)
{

}

public void deleteTextbook(String title)
{   

}

public String toString()
{
    return catalogue.toString(); 
}
}
```

Driver Class

```
package Ex1;

public class Drivermain 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Textbook javaBook = new Textbook ("Computer Science", 
            "Java Software Solutions", "Lewis/Loftus", 2015, 163.45);

    Textbook dataBook = new Textbook ("Computer Science", 
            "Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in Java,", 
            "Mark A. Weiss", 2015, 181.90);

    Textbook calcBook = new Textbook ("Mathematics", 
            "Calculus Plus NEW MyMathLab", "Briggs/Cochran/Gillett",
            2015, 236.90);

    Textbook osBook = new Textbook ("Computer Science", 
            "Operating Systems: Internals and Design Principles",
            "William Stallings", 2015, 205.70);

    Textbook historyBook = new Textbook ("History", 
            "History of the Canadian Peoples: Beginnings to 1867, Vol. 1",
            "Conard/Finkel/Fyson", 2015, 96.90);

    Catalogue bookCatalogue = new Catalogue();

    bookCatalogue.addTextbook(javaBook);
    bookCatalogue.addTextbook(dataBook);
    bookCatalogue.addTextbook(calcBook);
    bookCatalogue.addTextbook(osBook);
    bookCatalogue.addTextbook(historyBook);

    System.out.println(bookCatalogue);


    bookCatalogue.existTextbook("Java Software Solutions", "Lewis/Loftus");
    bookCatalogue.deleteTextbook("Java Software Solutions");

    }
}
```

Comment: Well search for a way to iterate over your list `catalogue` (for example with a "for each" loop) and then find a way to compare Strings in Java. Then you should know how to write these to methods.

Comment: For `existTextbook`, use a for-each loop. For `deleteTextbook`, use an `Iterator<Textbook>`.

Comment: +1 for attempted code and clear enough question. For future stuff consider reading this: you weren't exactly an offender of the XY problem, but it was pretty close.

 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of using methods from collections, you may want to deal with looking in your Arraylist yourself.

I'm not using a for each loop (just a for loop) because for delete it will cause a concurrent modification exception.

```
 package Ex1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Catalogue 
{
private ArrayList <Textbook> catalogue;

public Catalogue ()
{
    catalogue = new ArrayList<Textbook>();
}

public void addTextbook (Textbook t) 
{
    catalogue.add(t);
 }

public boolean existTextbook(String title, String author)
{
    for(int i =0; i<catalogue.Size(); i++){
       Textbook t = catalogue.get(i);
       //you'll want getter and setter methods
       if(t.author.equals(author)&&t.title.equals(title))
           return truel
    }
}

public void deleteTextbook(String title)
{   
    for(int i =0; i<catalogue.Size(); i++){
       Textbook t = catalogue.get(i);
       if(t.title.equals(title)){
          catalogue.remove(i);
       }
    }

}

public String toString()
{
    return catalogue.toString(); 
}
}
```

Happy Coding! Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks, was having some issues using for each loops - kind of makes sense looking at the exception in the API. 

There's one last wrinkle that I'm trying to search for a solution: is there an alternative to using a t.getTitle() or t.getAuthor() accessor method here? We've been advised: "Methods, getters and setters, are not required but you may add them for debugging  purposes.  They should  not be part of your final program to be handed in."

Comment: I can't fully imagine what that should mean. It may be worth asking for clarification. If you wanted to, I suppose you could have a function that checks whether two Textbook objects are equal. (one option is making textbooks comparable, lightly discussed in Amber's answer). This seems extravagant for what your assignment appears to be. Perhaps he would rather you access the member variables instead of getters and setters. If you get clarification and you still have questions, leave them here. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly using those methods you may consider just looping through the catalogue ArrayList yourself and testing if the current object matches the title (and author).
It might be overkill, but you could make Textbook implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) or write a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).